# ios ArialUnicodeMS returns other font

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts, chinese-locale

I'm currently trying to implement an App where I want to show chinese characters within a string, which also contains latin characters, e.g. "非常感谢您的订单。您为患者 PatientName"

In my app I'm using the following code:

```
[self.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialUnicodeMS" size:12.0f]]
```

If I test it (without adding ArialUnicodeMS as custom font) it works, but it doesn't use the ArialUnicodeMS, it's using a different font. 
If I add ArialUnicodeMS as custom font to my project and I'm trying the same line of code, then it uses the correct font.

So my question is, what kind of font is used by default for ArialUnicodeMS to show the chinese characters?

It's important for me, because I need to check if all characters fits to our company brand or if I need to use the "real" ArialUnicodeMS, which is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No version of iOS comes with the font "Arial Unicode MS" (see [this font list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202771)), but it is "downloadable". See [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Introduction/Intro.html) for an example of how to download it.

Comment: That's right, but the funny part is that it doesn't throw an exception if I use the line above without downloading the "Arial Unicode MS".
It returns a UIFont but I don't know which font it is. I know how to download and integrate the Arial Unicode MS, but I want to know how I can check if it is the correct font or which font is used.

Comment: Check `+[UIFont familyNames]` or `+[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]`.

Comment: If I test `UIFont *arialUnicodeMs = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialUnicodeMS" size:12.0f]` without downloading the font, then it returns a UIFont and if I check `arialUnicodeMs.familyName` then it's "Arial Unicode MS" but it isn't the Arial Unicode MS, because the characters are different. 
If I check the `+[UIFont familyNames]` then it doesn't contain a Arial Unicode MS in the family and either not in the names for family. So I'm still wondering which font is used by the system?

Comment: I need to correct my last comment, if I doesn't download the ArialUnicodeMS, then the `arialUnicodeMS.familyName` doesn't return "Arial Unicode MS", it returns ".PhoneFallback" as font name and as family name. What does this mean?

Comment: It uses a special `.PhoneFallback` font as a default if it can't find the font you name, which has generic shapes and is not specified to look like any particular commercially available font.

Comment: ok, so if I understand you correct, then the `.PhoneFallback` is an own font? Do you know if it is possible to look into it, to get all characters?

Comment: You can find the font file in the SDK, but it's not guaranteed to behave or look the same between versions of the OS.

Comment: That was what I'm looking for. Thank you.